# How can to implement recursion for loopback self relations?

Tags: node.js, mysql-workbench, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I have a self relation in my model. How to implement recursion for parent-child hierarchy using self-join in loopback upto N-level?

The code given below  will give us recursion only upto certain level but i want to implement it for N-LEVELS?

```
Menu.nest = function(callback) {
    Menu.find({
        "include":{
            "relation":"menus",
            "scope":{
                "include":{
                    "relation":"menus"
                }
            }
        }
    }, function(err, results) {
       if(err) return callback(err);
       callback(err, results);
    });
}
```

This is returning upto the limited number of levels

I want to implement recursion to implement upto N levels for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your maximum depth of query & data is set in `datasources.json` see [docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Querying-data.html) for details, so you'll want that to be your maximum N

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory",
    "maxDepthOfQuery": 5,
    "maxDepthOfData": 16
  }
}
```

I'm not able to test this right now, but this looks like a working/almost working snippet

```js
const o = {};

const assignFunc = (o) => {
  while(o.include) {
    o = o.include.scope;
  }
  o.include = {
    relation: "menus",
    scope:{}
  };
  return o;
}

function rec(o, n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return o;
  }
  assignFunc(o);
  return rec(o, n - 1);
};

console.log(rec({}, 10));
```